# Make canvas scrollable from mouse wheel on two windows

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

My GUI has two window pop ups. When I click on next, the scroll from the mouse wheel works on the window. When I click on another next button and another window opens, the scroll using the mousewheel on the last window stops working and only works on the latest window that is opened. How can I make the mouse wheel to work on the selected window simultaneously.

```
import tkinter as tk
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg, NavigationToolbar2Tk


all_figures1 = []
selected_figure1 = 0 
all_figures2 = []
selected_figure2 = 0 



class MyClass1():

    def __init__(self):

        self.sheets = [[1,2,3], [3,1,2], [1,5,1]]
        self.W = 2
        self.L = 5


    def plot_sheet(self, data):
        """plot single figure"""

        fig, ax = plt.subplots(1)

        ax.set_xlim([0, self.W]) 
        ax.set_ylim([0, self.L])

        ax.plot(data)

        return fig

    def generate_all_figures(self):
        """create all figures and keep them on list"""
        global all_figures

        for data in self.sheets:
            fig = self.plot_sheet(data)
            all_figures1.append(fig)
class MyClass2():

    def __init__(self):

        self.sheets = [[3,2,1], [2,5,3], [5,1,5]]
        self.W = 2
        self.L = 5


    def plot_sheet(self, data):
        """plot single figure"""

        fig, ax = plt.subplots(1)

        ax.set_xlim([0, self.W]) 
        ax.set_ylim([0, self.L])

        ax.plot(data)

        return fig

    def generate_all_figures(self):
        """create all figures and keep them on list"""
        global all_figures

        for data in self.sheets:
            fig = self.plot_sheet(data)
            all_figures2.append(fig)

dataPlot1 = None  
dataPlot2 = None  

def on_window1():

    def show_figure(number):
        global dataPlot1

        current_num = str(number+1)
        total_num = str(len(all_figures1))



        counter = tk.Label(top, text = current_num + "/" + total_num)
        counter.grid(row=4,column=0)



        # remove old canvas
        if dataPlot1 is not None: # at start there is no canvas to destroy
            dataPlot1.get_tk_widget().destroy()

        # get figure from list
        one_figure = all_figures1[number]

        # display canvas with figuere
        dataPlot = FigureCanvasTkAgg(one_figure, master=top)
        dataPlot.draw()
        dataPlot.get_tk_widget().grid(row=0, column=0)

        toolbar_frame = tk.Frame(top)
        toolbar_frame.grid(row=1,column=0)
        toolbar = NavigationToolbar2Tk(dataPlot, toolbar_frame)
        toolbar.update()

    def on_prev():
        global selected_figure1

        # get number of previous figure
        selected_figure1 -= 1
        if selected_figure1 < 0:
            selected_figure1 = len(all_figures1)-1

        show_figure(selected_figure1)

    def on_next():
        global selected_figure1

        # get number of next figure
        selected_figure1 += 1
        if selected_figure1 > len(all_figures1)-1:
            selected_figure1 = 0

        show_figure(selected_figure1)

    top = tk.Toplevel()
    top.wm_geometry("794x470")
    top.title('Optimized Map 1')

    selected_figure1 = 0
    dataPlot = None # default value for `show_figure`
    show_figure(selected_figure1)

    frame = tk.Frame(top)
    frame.grid(row=3, column=0)

    canvas1 = tk.Canvas(top, width=400, height=280)
    canvas1.grid(row=0,column=200)

    for i in range(40):
        l3 = tk.Label(canvas1, text="Number of Rectangles:" + str(i))
        canvas1.create_window(50,21*i, window=l3, anchor=tk.NW)


    myscrollbar= tk.Scrollbar(top,orient=tk.VERTICAL,command=canvas1.yview)
    myscrollbar.grid(row=0,column=200, sticky=tk.NS)
    canvas1.configure(yscrollcommand=myscrollbar.set)
    canvas1.bind_all('<MouseWheel>', lambda event: canvas1.yview_scroll(int(-1*(event.delta/120)), "units"))
    canvas1.configure(scrollregion=canvas1.bbox("all"))


    #l4 = tk.Label(canvas1, text="Number of Rectangles:")
    #canvas1.create_window(50,21, window=l4, anchor=tk.NW)

    b1 = tk.Button(frame, text="<<", command=on_prev)
    b1.grid(row=2, column=0)


    b2 = tk.Button(frame, text=">>", command=on_next)
    b2.grid(row=2, column=1)

    b4 = tk.Button(frame, text="Save", command=save_file)
    b4.grid(row=5, column=0)

def on_window2():

    def show_figure(number):
        global dataPlot2

        current_num = str(number+1)
        total_num = str(len(all_figures2))


        counter = tk.Label(top, text = current_num + "/" + total_num)
        counter.grid(row=4,column=0)



        # remove old canvas
        if dataPlot2 is not None: # at start there is no canvas to destroy
            dataPlot2.get_tk_widget().destroy()

        # get figure from list
        one_figure = all_figures2[number]

        # display canvas with figuere
        dataPlot = FigureCanvasTkAgg(one_figure, master=top)
        dataPlot.draw()
        dataPlot.get_tk_widget().grid(row=0, column=0)

        toolbar_frame = tk.Frame(top)
        toolbar_frame.grid(row=1,column=0)
        toolbar = NavigationToolbar2Tk(dataPlot, toolbar_frame)
        toolbar.update()




    def on_prev():
        global selected_figure2

        # get number of previous figure
        selected_figure2 -= 1
        if selected_figure2 < 0:
            selected_figure2 = len(all_figures2)-1

        show_figure(selected_figure2)

    def on_next():
        global selected_figure2

        # get number of next figure
        selected_figure2 += 1
        if selected_figure2 > len(all_figures2)-1:
            selected_figure2 = 0

        show_figure(selected_figure2)

    top = tk.Toplevel()
    top.wm_geometry("794x370")
    top.title('Optimized Map2')



    selected_figure2 = 0
    dataPlot = None # default value for `show_figure`
    show_figure(selected_figure2)


    frame = tk.Frame(top)
    frame.grid(row=3, column=0)

    canvas = tk.Canvas(top, width=400, height=280)
    canvas.grid(row=0,column=200)

    for i in range(40):
        l3 = tk.Label(canvas, text="Number of Rectangles:" + str(i))
        canvas.create_window(50,21*i, window=l3, anchor=tk.NW)


    myscrollbar= tk.Scrollbar(top,orient=tk.VERTICAL,command=canvas.yview)
    myscrollbar.grid(row=0,column=200, sticky=tk.NS)
    canvas.configure(yscrollcommand=myscrollbar.set)
    canvas.bind_all('<MouseWheel>', lambda event: canvas.yview_scroll(int(-1*(event.delta/120)), "units"))
    canvas.configure(scrollregion=canvas.bbox("all"))

    b1 = tk.Button(frame, text="<<", command=on_prev)
    b1.grid(row=2, column=0)

    b2 = tk.Button(frame, text=">>", command=on_next)
    b2.grid(row=2, column=1)




window = tk.Tk()

mc1 = MyClass1()
mc1.generate_all_figures()

mc2 = MyClass2()
mc2.generate_all_figures()



b1 = tk.Button(window, text="Next", command=on_window1)
b1.grid(row=0, column=0)

b2 = tk.Button(window, text="Next", command=on_window2)
b2.grid(row=1, column=0)

window.mainloop()
```

Comment: what if you click on previous window to set focus and then use wheel on its scrollbar ? On Linux Mint it works correctly without clicking - I have to only keep mouse's cursor on scrollbar.

Comment: `MyClass1` and `MyClass2` are identicall except data so you could create one class and create instncess with different arguments `MyClass([3,2,1], [2,5,3], [5,1,5]])` , `MyClass([[1,2,3], [3,1,2], [1,5,1]])`. You could also keep `all_figures` and `selected_figure` inside class as `self.all_figures`, `self.selected_figure`. Similar with `on_window1`, `on_window2` - it could be one function (or even class) which you run with different arguments - `on_window(mc1, selected_figure1)`